# pymongo empty cursor with count() > 0

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am trying to make some kind of a queue where many processes can access and atomically take an item to process:

```
while True:

  s= db.queue.find_and_modify({'service':'lock'},{'$set':{'locked':True}},upsert=True,new=False) # serves as a lock over the whole collection

  if s and s['locked']: # already locked by another process
    time.sleep(random.randint(2,10)) # sleep and try again
    continue
  else: # the lock was put by this process (atomic find_and_modify)
    db.queue.update({'service':'lock'},{'$set':{'pid':process_id}}, upsert=True) # register the process who put the lock

  res = db.queue.find({'when':{'$lte':last},'locked':False}).limit(1).sort('when',1) #select an available item

  to_return = None #initialize with None

  if res.count():  # 1 or more
     to_return = res[0]  #get the first item 
     to_return['locked'] = True      # lock it
     to_return['pid'] = process_id   # register the process locking it
     db.queue.save(to_return)

  db.queue.update({'service':'lock'},{'$set':{'locked':False}}) # remove the global lock

  return to_return
```

Sometimes I see a process going DEFUNCT
and in the logs I see the exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "driver.py", line 22, in getUserFromQueue
    to_return = res[0]

IndexError("no such item for Cursor instance")
```

Which means that the cursor `res` is empty,
but how could it be empty since there is a global lock: only one process querying for items, and it already passed the condition `if res.count()` ,ie. there is at least one item in the cursor

The reason I had to create a global lock is I cannot use limit and sort with find_and_modify